# How to cast from List<Double> to double[] in Java?

Tags: java, list, casting, double

I have a variable like that:

```
List<Double> frameList =  new ArrayList<Double>();

/* Double elements has added to frameList */
```

How can I have a new variable has a type of `double[]` from that variable in Java with high performance?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

High performance - every `Double` object wraps a single `double` value. If you want to store all these values into a `double[]` array, then you *have* to iterate over the collection of `Double` instances. A `O(1)` mapping is not possible, this should be the fastest you can get:

```
 double[] target = new double[doubles.size()];
 for (int i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
    target[i] = doubles.get(i).doubleValue();  // java 1.4 style
    // or:
    target[i] = doubles.get(i);                // java 1.5+ style (outboxing)
 }
```

---

Thanks for the additional question in the comments ;) Here's the sourcecode of the fitting `ArrayUtils#toPrimitive` method:

```
public static double[] toPrimitive(Double[] array) {
  if (array == null) {
    return null;
  } else if (array.length == 0) {
    return EMPTY_DOUBLE_ARRAY;
  }
  final double[] result = new double[array.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    result[i] = array[i].doubleValue();
  }
  return result;
}
```

(And trust me, I didn't use it for my first answer - even though it looks ... pretty similiar :-D )

By the way, the complexity of Marcelos answer is O(2n), because it iterates twice (behind the scenes): first to make a `Double[]` from the list, then to unwrap the `double` values.

Comment: how about comparing your suggestion about performance with @Marcelo Hernández Rish's sugesstion?

Comment: @kamaci Andreas' answer is optimal.

Comment: Well technically speaking, O(2n) = O(n)

Comment: I suggest to avoid `doubles.get(i)`, although we know that the questioner provided an ArrayList. An approach like this: 
`double[] tmp = new double[doubles.size()];
 int idx = 0;
 for (Double d : doubles) {
 tmp[idx] = d;
 idx++;
 }` works good for every List (and even Collection).

Answer (score 123):

With [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), you can do it this way.

```
double[] arr = frameList.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray(); //via method reference
double[] arr = frameList.stream().mapToDouble(d -> d).toArray(); //identity function, Java unboxes automatically to get the double value
```

What it does is :

- get the `Stream<Double>` from the list
- map each double instance to its primitive value, resulting in a `DoubleStream`
- call `toArray()` to get the array.

Comment: What is the complexity for your answer behind the scenes?

Comment: @kamaci Each element of the pipeline will be visited once, so O(n) for a basic sequential pipeline (`map` returns a lazy stream, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696317/java-8-find-first-element-by-predicate/23696571#23696571).

Answer (score 36):

[Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) has a method to do this for you: [double[] Doubles.toArray(Collection<Double>)](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Doubles.html#toArray%28java.util.Collection%29)

This isn't necessarily going to be any faster than just looping through the `Collection` and adding each `Double` object to the array, but it's a lot less for you to write.

Answer (score 9):

As per your question,

```
List<Double> frameList =  new ArrayList<Double>();
```

1. First you have to convert `List<Double>` to `Double[]` by using

   ```
   Double[] array = frameList.toArray(new Double[frameList.size()]);
   ```
2. Next you can convert `Double[]` to `double[]` using

   ```
   double[] doubleArray = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(array);
   ```

You can directly use it in one line:

```
double[] array = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(frameList.toArray(new Double[frameList.size()]));
```

Comment: It's important to note that `ArrayUtils` is part of the Apache library, so not standard Java: `org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils`. But it's a good solution anyway.

Comment: So this is only retelling what [this much older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6018298/2711488) already said, but in contrast to the older answer, posted at a time when the [better solution already existed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27531513/2711488) . This answer even copies the behavior of pre-sizing the array passed to `toArray` [which has been proven to be less efficient](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/) than `toArray(new Double[0])`

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `ArrayUtils` class from commons-lang to obtain a `double[]` from a `Double[]`.

```
Double[] ds = frameList.toArray(new Double[frameList.size()]);
...
double[] d = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(ds);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can convert to a `Double[]` by calling `frameList.toArray(new Double[frameList.size()])`, but you'll need to iterate the list/array to convert to `double[]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use primitive collections from [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/) and avoid boxing altogether.

```
DoubleList frameList = DoubleLists.mutable.empty();
double[] arr = frameList.toArray();
```

If you can't or don't want to initialize a `DoubleList`:

```
List<Double> frames = new ArrayList<>();
double[] arr = ListAdapter.adapt(frames).asLazy().collectDouble(each -> each).toArray();
```

Note: I am a contributor to Eclipse Collections.

Comment: Why should anyone use that 3rd party library `ListAdapter.adapt(frames).asLazy().collectDouble(each -> each).toArray();` when there is already the builtin solution `frames.stream().mapToDouble(each -> each).toArray();` which is even simpler?