# How do I convert a java ArrayList<Double> to the equivalent double[]

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to cast from List<Double> to double[] in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018267/how-to-cast-from-listdouble-to-double-in-java)

So far the only method I can get working is to loop through the entire array. I was hoping for something along the lines of:

```
ArrayList<Double> myArrayList = ... // initiaize
double[] myArray = ... // magic line here
```

Comment: Why you need do it? You want to iterate over `myArrayList`?

Comment: double != Double. No magic available.

Comment: Times like this I'm glad I work in .NET. ;-)

Comment: there are other kinds of problems in .Net that Java doesn't have, and I'd rather have Java's problems than .Net ones :)

Answer (score 5):

Use **[Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)** : [**Doubles.toArray**](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Doubles.html#toArray%28java.util.Collection%29)

```
myArray = Doubles.toArray(myArrayList);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot go from `ArrayList<Double>` to `double[]` with a single call using the sandard Java API. However, take a look at the [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html) class available from [Apache's site](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).

On a side note, if you need to change your `ArrayList` into a primitive array, perhaps your problem is somewhere else. If you explain further exactly what you are trying to achieve, we could provide you better help than a simple API hack.

Comment: oh... I misread the `Double`, no it won't... correcting answer