# Converting a Double Array list to a double array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am wanting to convert my double ArrayList to a double array but I am unsure how. Here is my current code listing :

```
ArrayList<Double> aL= new ArrayList<Double>();  
double x[] = new double[aL.size()];
aL.add(10.0);  
aL.add(5.0);  
aL.add(2.0);
for(int i =0; i < x.length; i++){
//some code
}
```

But then I am not sure where to go and I am unable to find something on the internet/ in books to give me any insight. Thanks.

Comment: This question shows no effort.  Please try consulting the [documentation for List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Comment: It's pretty straightforward; you've got everything you need in your code (except the contents of the loop). What problems are you having?

Comment: Helpful links: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Here's [one duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6018267/778118)... and [another](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6147421/778118)... and [another](http://stackoverflow.com/q/960431/778118)... It's a shame that anybody would bother to answer a question like this.  It should be downvoated and closed.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

First, you need to create your ArrayList.  Then you need to create your array.

```
List<Double> aL= new ArrayList<Double>();  
aL.add(10.0D);  
aL.add(5.0D);  
aL.add(2.0D);

double x[] = new double[aL.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
     x[i] = al.get(i);
}
```

You can use an ArrayList method to copy the ArrayList to an array.

```
List<Double> aL= new ArrayList<Double>();  
aL.add(10.0D);  
aL.add(5.0D);  
aL.add(2.0D);

double x[] = aL.toArray();
```

Comment: This is not going to work you will get a compile time  :Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object[] to double[]

Answer (score -2):

You can use Collection API to convert list to array. Try uL.toArray();

Comment: Nope. That will not work. See Gourabp's comment above.