# How do I convert an ArrayList of integers to a double[]?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have set up the following ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Integer> myIntegerValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myIntegerValues.add(0);
myIntegerValues.add(1);
myIntegerValues.add(0);
myIntegerValues.add(1);
```

I want to convert this to a `double[]` and run a simple piece of code like this

```
double[] myList = {1.9, 2.9, 3.4, 3.5, 2.9, 3.8, 10.2};        
for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(myList[i] + " ");
}
```

How do I convert an `ArrayList` to a `double[]`?

I found this link
[How to cast from List<Double> to double[] in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018267/how-to-cast-from-listdouble-to-double-in-java)
but I'm not sure if this answers my question or not.

Comment: Do you want 1 to be converted as 1.9 or 1.3 or something like that? How does anyone know what 1 in real value is unless you feed it out? You can though convert it from 1 to 1.0

Comment: Did you have a look to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718554/how-to-convert-an-arraylist-containing-integers-to-primitive-int-array ? Try to add a cast

Comment: The java statistical package I am using requires `double[]` as an input. The ArrayList doesn't work as an input. So I am trying to convert the numbers in my ArrayList so that I can use them in the statistical package datastructures.

Comment: Best thing to do is to create an array of matching size and then iterate over the entries, casting as you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing to do is to create an array of matching size and then iterate over the entries, casting as you go.

```
double[] myList = new double[myIntegerValues.size()];
for (int i=0; i<myIntegerValues.size(); i++) {
   myList[i] = (double) myIntegerValues.get(i);
}
```

Note, while I could use an iterator, using indexes makes the one to one relationship clear.

Answer (score 5):

```
double[] array = myIntegerValues.stream().mapToDouble(i -> (double) i).toArray();
```

Comment: Could also use `Integer::doubleValue` instead of the lambda.

Comment: @JornVernee, yeap, but for OP it can be slightly unobvious

Comment: aw no fair, I like being the one to throw up the Java 8 answers.

Comment: I tried this solution and couldn't get it to work. It looks more elegant than the one I accepted and I would prefer to accept yours if it is more efficient. But I don't see the ArrayList anywhere in your line of code. I'm not sure how it is therefore supposed to work.

Comment: @Mr.NoName, the `list` variable was your `ArrayList`, I renamed it to `myIntegerValues`

Answer (score 0):

Declare a double arry of the size of the arraylist first, since arrays aren't dynamic.

```
double[] doublesList = new double[myIntegerValues.size()];
```

then loop through and convert each one

```
int x = 0;
for(Integer i : myIntegerValues){
    doublesList[x] = (double)i;
    x++;
}
```