# Predict with a List<Double>

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have a trained `RandomForestModel` object from a libsvm file and would now like to call the predict method with that model using a `List<Double>` as features. How can I convert a `List<Double>` to the necessary input in Java and see the predicted target class?

From what I can tell, predict(...) takes in a `JavaRDD<Vector>` but I'm uncertain how to convert a `List<Double>` to that .

Comment: I'm assuming the one I should use is https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/tree/model/RandomForestModel.html#predict-org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD-

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation of the JavaRDD class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a browse of the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/tree/model/RandomForestModel.html), it looks like `RandomForestModel` can also call `predict` on a `Vector`. You can convert a `List<Double>` to a `DenseVector` ([docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/DenseVector.html)) by converting your list to a `double` array as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6018267/2387370) question and then doing `new DenseVector(double_array)`.

Comment: Before I saw this, I ended up doing Vector dv = Vectors.dense(Doubles.toArray(myListOfDoubles)), where Doubles.toArray comes from Guava

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the sparsity of your data, you can write a `map` transformation from List to Vector using either [SparseVector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/SparseVector.html#SparseVector-int-int:A-double:A-) or [DenseVector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/DenseVector.html)

```
int length = yourList.size();
double[] inputArray = new double[length];
yourList.toArray(inputArray);
Vector inputVector = new DenseVector(inputArray);
```